# how docker containers can be replaced while its running

Tags: docker

I have a container named  'basecontainer' created from the image named alpine. I created a new image named 'newalpine' by copying some files in alpine image using Dockerfile. My question is "How can i replace that basecontainer with the container that will be created using newly created image on the fly ?"

Comment: This cannot be done. Stop the old container and start the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with standalone Docker container, because Docker is only responsible for your container runtime.

What you need is a RollingUpdate, which could be done by Kubernetes for instance.
See: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/rolling-update-replication-controller/

Kubernetes RollingUpdate can be used for on the fly updates. If you have a running container and you want to update that container, Kubernetes starts the second container while the old one is running. When the updated container is ready for work, the old one is automatically shut down by the engine.

I know, sounds like much overhead, but otherwise you have to do this rolling update procedure by yourself.

Comment: Yes that was not possible for standalone container. But if i deploy it as a service it can be updated using docker service update.